# (Python) Match combine counts of the inverse of A and B as B and A

Tags: python, pandas

Don't know if this is the best way to describe this but I have two columns A and B and I need to combine the counts of A and B as the same as B and A (Specifically airports if anyone is interested, however for this business application NYC => LA is the same as LA => NYC so I'm trying to combine areas where NYC => LA and LA => NYC as the same.)

I've tried a few things in Python to get this done. I did something at a previous job a few years ago so I know it's not hard just Tuesday brain. Goal would be a simple code snippet that allows me to combine the counts of A=>B and B=>A as one.

Comment: can you provide some example of how your file structure look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file looks like that:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')


pairs = set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in df[['A','B']].to_numpy()) # create a set of tuples containing unique pairs of airports


combined_counts = {} # create a new dictionary to store the combined counts

# iterate over the pairs of airports
for pair in pairs:
    airport1, airport2 = pair
    # add the counts of A=>B and B=>A together
    count = df[(df['A'] == airport1) & (df['B'] == airport2)]['count'].sum() + df[(df['A'] == airport2) & (df['B'] == airport1)]['count'].sum()
    # store the result in the new dictionary
    combined_counts[pair] = count
df_result = pd.DataFrame(list(combined_counts.items()), columns = ['Airport Pair', 'Count'])
print(df_result)
```

Output will be:

```
Airport Pair  Count
0    (LA, NYC)     15
1    (CHI, SF)     23
2    (NYC, SF)     19
```